# Integrating Angular test Cases in Azure Pipelines

Tags: angular, automated-tests, karma-jasmine, azure-pipelines

Can anybody provide the information as how we can integrate Angular test cases (Jasmine/Karma) into Azure Pipelines.Where are the test cases result displayed after the build pipeline is executed succesfully

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running Jasmine tests on Azure DevOps as part of automated build process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977909/running-jasmine-tests-on-azure-devops-as-part-of-automated-build-process)

Answer (score 8):

Check case [Running Jasmine tests on Azure DevOps as part of automated build process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977909/running-jasmine-tests-on-azure-devops-as-part-of-automated-build-process)

You can do this through the following script and tasks:

1. run [`ng test`](https://angular.io/cli/test)
2. publish test results with [`PublishTestResults`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) task
3. publish code coverage results with [`PublishCodeCoverageResults`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-code-coverage-results?view=azure-devops) task

In the [Azure Pipelines YAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema) file, this could look as follows:

```
# perform unit-tets and publish test and code coverage results
- script: |
    npx ng test --watch=false --karmaConfig karma.conf.ci.js --code-coverage
  displayName: 'perform unit tests'    

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
    testResultsFiles: '**/TESTS-*.xml'
  displayName: 'publish unit test results'

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  displayName: 'publish code coverage report'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
    summaryFileLocation: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml'
    failIfCoverageEmpty: true
```

Comment: Thanks for that info, that really helps and i tried implementing in my current project and with few changes here and there all looks good.

Comment: Hi Dong, I did Accept your answer

Comment: Running a script similar to above, after a successful build, gives me "command not found: ng" - what gives?